# how to change a field of object's type or create a similar object with data transfer

Tags: java, object, arraylist, types

I am working on Spring Boot with MongoDB. In one of my entities, I declared a field of type ArrayList in order to store another object's mongoId.

Lets say they are A and B:

```
public class A implements Serializable {
    bla bla bla
    private ArrayList<String> bs;

    public A(){
        this.bs = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}

public class B implements Serializable {
    bla bla bla...
    some fields...
}
```

Now, I want to return the object A as a whole in 1 request, which means I want to return the object with an array of B objects field, not with String array.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Why don't you store it as reference when you put it in the DB?

Comment: What do you mean by storing as reference? Currently I am using MongoDB and putting B's ids into the array in A.

Comment: Just put the B instances in the ArrayList instead of the id.

Comment: I would like to find another solution for this. Your solution will affect my queries harsh.

Comment: there is no way you can serialize the B to a string ?